# Re-Sizing GridPane Buttons Without Text

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a JavaFX application that involves buttons laid out upon a GridPane. I've set the buttons max height and max width using:

```
button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_Value);
```

and:

```
button.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_Value);
```

As well as:

```
GridPane.setFillWidth(button, true);
```

However my button only extends to the row/column span specified within:

```
grid.add();
```

When there is text on the button, is their any way of extending the size of the button without it having a text value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setMaxHeight()/setMaxWidth() sets the *maximum* size for the button, as in it cannot grow bigger than that. You want to set the *minimum* size, so that it is *at least* that big. Change it to setMinHeight()/setMinWidth():

```
button.setMinWidth(Double.MAX_Value);
button.setMinHeight(Double.MAX_Value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I just needed a better understanding of how buttons actually work in JavaFX - I'm a complete beginner. Safe to say you don't find a solution when what you've tried is completely off the mark, cheers for taking the time to help :)  EDIT: After trying this out, the button now simply doesn't appear?

Comment: No problem. Tip for future question-asking: Include the specific type of Object you are using. It wasn't too hard to figure out that you were using an FX button, but someone who didn't read it as closely may have thought you were talking about a JButton object

Comment: I'm using grid.add(button, 0, 0, 2, 2).

Comment: `grid.add()` is the function you are using. The type of Object of the button would be whatever you used to declare the `button` variable. I assume it is something like `Button button = new Button();`